# Show that topologies are the same

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I just read a proof where it was said that if for each element in the topology 2 we find an element in topology 1 that is contained in this set and vice versa, then they are the same. How do I see that this is equivalent to the notion that the topologies are subsets of each other? By the way, one of them was induced by a metric.

Comment: @Fermat I think the OP asks this: Let $\mathcal{T}_{1}$ and $\mathcal{T}_{2}$ be topologies on the
same set. Is it true that $\forall U\in\mathcal{T}_{i}\exists V\in\mathcal{T}_{2-i}\; V\subset U$
for $i=1,2$ implies that $\mathcal{T}_{1}=\mathcal{T}_{2}$? Lipschitz, please correct me if my interpretation is not okay.

Comment: You do not assume that both topologies are induced by a metric ?

Comment: For each element in topology 2 you can *always* find an element in topology 1 that is contained in this set: the empty set. And vice versa off course. So in general this cannot be true. Spread some light over this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated, the observation made is incorrect, as noted in the [comment by drhab](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/806353/show-that-topologies-are-the-same#comment1666560_806353) above:

> For each element in topology 2 you can *always* find an element in topology 1 that is contained in this set: the empty set. And vice versa off course. So in general this cannot be true. Spread some light over this.

Even without being quite so facetious it is false: Let $\mathcal{O}_{\text{m}}$ denote the usual (metric) topology on $\mathbb{R}$, and let $\mathcal{O}_{\text{S}}$ denote the Sorgenfrey (lower-limit) topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

- Given any (nonempty) $U \in \mathcal{O}_{\text{m}}$ we can find $a < b$ such that $(a,b) \subseteq U$, and so $[ \frac{ a+b}{2} , b ) \subseteq (a,b) \subseteq U$, and $[ \frac{ a+b}{2} , b ) \in \mathcal{O}_{\text{S}}$.
- Given any (nonempty) $V \in \mathcal{O}_{\text{S}}$ we can find $a < b$ such that $[a,b) \subseteq V$, and so $(a,b) \subseteq [a,b) \subseteq V$ and $(a,b) \in \mathcal{O}_{\text{m}}$.

---

The correct statement would be the following:

> Suppose that $\mathcal{O}_1$ and $\mathcal{O}_2$ are two topologies on a set $X$.  Then $\mathcal{O}_1$ and $\mathcal{O}_1$ are the same iff the following two things hold:
>
> 1. Given any $U \in \mathcal{O}_1$ and any $x \in U$ there is a $V \in \mathcal{O}_2$ such that $x \in V \subseteq U$; and
> 2. Given any $V \in \mathcal{O}_2$ and any $x \in V$ there is a $U \in \mathcal{O}_1$ such that $x \in U \subseteq V$.

The analogous statement is also true for bases for topologies on $X$:

> Suppose that $\mathcal{B}_1$ and $\mathcal{B}_2$ are two bases for topologies on a set $X$.  Then the topologies generated by $\mathcal{B}_1$ and $\mathcal{B}_1$ coincide iff the following two things hold:
>
> 1. Given any $U \in \mathcal{B}_1$ and any $x \in U$ there is a $V \in \mathcal{B}_2$ such that $x \in V \subseteq U$; and
> 2. Given any $V \in \mathcal{B}_2$ and any $x \in V$ there is a $U \in \mathcal{B}_1$ such that $x \in U \subseteq V$.

---

**Added:**

Consider the following slightly modified version of the given statement:

> For each nonempty $U \subseteq X$ open with respect to the first topology, there is a nonempty $V \subseteq Y$ open with respect to the second topology such that $V \subseteq U$, and *vice versa*.

What this statement says is that every (nonempty) open set in the first topology has nonempty interior with respect to the second topology (and *vice versa*).

It should be noted that two topologies on a set $X$ sharing this property may not even be *comparable* (let alone the same).  The simplest example I can think of are the following topologies on $\mathbb{R}$: the Sorgenfrey (lower-limit) topology generated by $\{ [a,b) : a < b \}$ and the "upper-limit" topology, generated by $\{ ( a , b] : a < b \}$.  (Of note is that while these topologies are not comparable, they are homeomorphic via the mapping $x \mapsto -x$.)